# Example files HMC memory gem5 not working

Tags: gem5

I am trying to execute the configs/example/hmc_hello.py file in gem5 with the following commands:

```
build/X86/gem5.opt configs/example/hmc_hello.py
```

With this I get the following error message:

```
panic: panic condition !intMasterPort.isConnected() occurred: Int port not connected to anything!
```

I have also tried setting the architecture parameter.

```
build/X86/gem5.opt configs/example/hmc_hello.py --arch same
```

With this I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "build/X86/python/m5/main.py", line 457, in main
    exec(filecode, scope)
  File "configs/example/hmc_hello.py", line 64, in <module>
    system.cpu.icache_port = system.membus.slave
  File "build/X86/python/m5/SimObject.py", line 1277, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(err_string)
AttributeError: object 'System' has no attribute 'membus'
  (C++ object is not yet constructed, so wrapped C++ methods are unavailable.)
```

I am very confused because I am not changing anything in the files. I have not found anyone reporting problems with this file. Am I doing something wrong??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since this looks like a bug, I'd just open a ticket at: https://gem5.atlassian.net/browse/GEM5

Comment: OK, I have submitted an issue, thanks for the advice!

Comment: Great! Let's also link to it :-) https://gem5.atlassian.net/browse/GEM5-700

Answer (score 0):

panic: panic condition !intMasterPort.isConnected() occurred: Int port not connected to anything!
This error is due to arch X86, it needs a interrupt. change X86 to ARM can solve it!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).